# What kind of modifications the AE86's have had in Initial D?

Tags: initial-d

I am not that interested in automotive (aviation all the way DC-3) but after seeing "Pimp My Reich" (I strongly suggest you to watch it, the ending is great) I learned there is a manga and an anime called Initial D. As I learned, there were 3 AE86's in the whole series but what about the modifications? Were "performance" modifications ever used in the series? They can be simple engine part replacements or whole engine/aspiration type replacements.

Simply put: did anyone of the AE86's had any kind of performance mods? Also I want to make a replica of it in racing sims. So should I use carbon fiber or black painting for the hood? What is the history of hood part replacement throughout the series?

Comment: https://initiald.fandom.com/wiki/Toyota_AE86 This should be a helpful site, although it's been a year since you asked the question. The facts are based upon mostly the manga.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To put them simply I list them one by one (these are the things that are mentioned or can be seen in the anime, so things like brands of wheel rims for example which are not mentioned in the anime I will not mention them):

1. Takumi's AE86
   Before his engine blowout, he used a modified 4A-GE engine. After his engine blowout, his dad changed it to a Group A engine and changed his tachometer to cope with the high-revving environment of the engine. During his time in Project D, his suspension is also changed to a new one after he 'won' his battle with God Hand, although it wasn't stated what modifications are made to the suspension if I remember correctly. Also his change from stock to carbon hood before his battle with Tachi Tomoyuki from the graduate of Toudou School
2. Wataru's AE86
   Wataru's AE86 is an interesting one as it has the most apparent or mentioned changes. First he uses a turbo for his engine. After he lost his battle with Takumi at the end of stage 2, he changed from turbo to supercharger since he felt unsatisfied with his turbo performance. At the same time, he also changed from stock hood to carbon hood.
3. Shinji's AE86
   Shinji's AE86 is a stock sedan AE86. It doesn't have any performance change as far as I'm concerned.

And to answer your question regarding the replica, I suggest to use a black-painted hood as the carbon hood in some games is too gray-ish instead of black-ish like Takumi's.

Comment: Thanks. I think the carbon hoods in Forza Motorsport 4 are black enough :)

Comment: You're welcome ! :)